# Object pushed into subarray saved as string in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save an object modeled using Mongoose, after pushing an object into a sub array.

```
MyObject.findOne({name:'someName'}, function (err, myObject) {
    if (err) throw err;
    myObject.subArray.push({someKey: 'someString'});
    myObject.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log()
    });
}
```

When I run the following query in the mongo shell:

```
db.myobjects.find({name:'someName'})
```

I get the following response:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d35cefa5c07abb14955bc3"),
    "name" : "someName",
    "subArray" : [
        "[object Object]"
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the object pushed into `subArray` has been saved as a string.

The Schema for the MyObject model is as follows:

```
var MyObjectSchema = new Mongoose.Schema ({
    name : String,
    subArray : [{
        someKey : String
    }]
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the schema?

Comment: @wdberkeley I have updated the question with the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by creating a sub document schema:

```
var SubArraySchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    someKey : String
}, {_id : false});

var MyObjectSchema = new Mongoose.Schema ({
    name : String,
    subArray : [SubArraySchema]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your `myObject.subArray.push({someKey: 'someString'});`

must be `myObject['subArray'] = [{someKey: 'someString'}];`

Comment: But this would not add to the existing array, simply replace it.